# Передача переменного количества параметров в С

Tags: c, функции

Имеем функции:

```
void foo(Object a, arg...)  
void bar(arg...)
```

и проблема в том, как передать из функции `foo` параметры в функцию `bar`?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это си???)))

Comment: @faoxis: А что удивительного? Object'om может быть структура к примеру.

Comment: @Yami, точнее typedef

Comment: а что за `arg` перед многоточием?

Comment: Это суржик какой-то, а не С. К С, разумеется, такой синтаксис никакого отношения не имеет. Что такое `arg...`?

Answer (score 2):

Передаете [va_list](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) и аргумент, который его устанавливает в `va_start`.

Вот пример (только почитайте сначала man-ы на [vsnprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vsnprintf) и [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html))

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
static int
asprintf (char **ps, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  //   puts("my asprintf");
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  int rc = vsnprintf(*ps, 0, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  if (rc >= 0) {
    if ((*ps = (char *)malloc(rc + 2))) {
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      rc = vsnprintf(*ps, rc + 1, fmt, ap);
      va_end(ap);
    } else
      rc = -1;
  }

  return rc;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Добавлю, что корректного способа передать параметры из `foo()` именно в такую `bar()`, как она объявлена в вопросе (со скидкой на то что там опечатка) **нет**...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, со скидкой на опечатки -- `va_start(ap, arg); bar(arg, ap);` Это если предположить, что первый аргумент `Object a` к делу не относится

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, я тут немного подумал... Действительно, в этом случае нужен вот такой bar --  `bar(typeof(arg), va_list)` (в самом деле, `bar(typeof(arg), ...)` вызвать опианным образом не удастся)

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, есть функция со следующей сигнатурой:

```
void foo (unsigned int argcount, ...);
```

Если я правильно понял, то ваша цель - передать все её значения аргументов в некую функцию **bar**. Тогда сигнатура для неё может быть следующей :

```
void bar(unsigned int argcount, va_list args);
```

для `bar` нужно ,минимум, 2 аргумента, поскольку по-другому количество переменных в `va_list` мы не сможем узнать.

Предоставлю рабочий пример,где функция **bar** просто отображает аргументы,которые она приняла от **foo**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

 void bar(unsigned int argcount, va_list bar_args)
 {
    unsigned int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < argcount; counter++ )
        /*после каждого вызова va_arg на его месте будет следующий элемент из va_list*/
        printf("%d\n", va_arg(bar_args, int ) ); /* передаю целочисленный тип, поэтому выбрал int */
 }

 void foo (unsigned int argcount, ...)
 {
    va_list foo_args;
    va_start( foo_args, argcount );
    /*передаём количество аргументов и сам va_list соответственно*/
    bar( argcount, foo_args );
    va_end( foo_args );
 }

 int main()
 {
    /* первое число - количество аргументов, далее - сами аргументы */
    foo(7,1,3,3,7,-2,2,8);
    return 0;
 }
```

Заметьте, что в **bar** нету уже никаких `va_start` и `va_end`: всё начинается и заканчивается в `foo`.

Судя по вашему вопросу, вы не работали с таким типом соглашения вызовов, поэтому ознакомьтесь хотя бы с тривиальным описанием [тут](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/vastart-vaend-vaarg), а если всё в порядке с английским, то ещё лучше - [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_start.htm) и [здесь](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html).

Ещё одна заметка : для хранения количества аргументов ,будь-то для `va_list`'a или для обычного массива, лучше используйте беззнаковый  целочисленный тип (например, `unsigned int`), а ещё лучше - использовать ко всему прочему платформонезависимый тип (например, `size_t`) : сможете избежать неприятных ошибок.